# Bisection method in C++

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to create a program in C++ that will use the bisection method on a cubic function to find a root of that cubic function. Now I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int functie(double a,double b,double c,double d,double x){
    double y;
    y = (a*x*x*x + b*x*x + c*x + d);
    return y;
}

int main(){

    int a,b,c,d;//no comment

    cout << "enter of form: ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d (integers)" << endl << "a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << endl << "b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << endl << "c: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << endl << "d: ";
    cin >> d;

    double min, max, temp;

    min = -100;
    max = 108.54267542;
    while(functie(a,b,c,d,max) == 0 ||functie(a,b,c,d,min) == 0 ){
    temp = (max + min)/2;
    if(functie(a,b,c,d,min) < 0 && functie(a,b,c,d,temp) < 0 || functie(a,b,c,d,min) > 0 && functie(a,b,c,d,temp) > 0){
           min = temp;
    } else {max = temp;}
    }
    cout << min << endl;
    cout << max << endl;
    cout << temp << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work; the cout's at the end of the program only output the input values. 
(and in case you were wondering why my max value is so weird, is to prevent that when max is +100 and the root is at 0, then the program will crash...)

So if you have got some time and want to check this, thank you.

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors by inspection is not productive.  You can solve this by stepping through your code in a debugger, or by printing out intermediate values.

Comment: By the way how do you do vote for closing (i am not saying I am going to vote for this particular question).

Comment: @BorisStrandjev You'll need 3000 reputation to be able to close questions.

Comment: Your code doesn't check that f(min) and f(max) actually have different signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's wrong. On this line:

```
while(functie(a,b,c,d,max) == 0 ||functie(a,b,c,d,min) == 0 )
```

The loop will execute only when the value returned from `functie` is zero. The values of `max` and `min` should never change.

And you have declared `functie` like this:

```
int functie(double a,double b,double c,double d,double x)
```

You're returning (and you should) a `double` value from `functie`, but because of the definition it's cast into an `int`.

Comment: You are correct in your observations, though I would like to add that words like `What's this?` are a bit harsh.

Comment: Oh my god! what have I done there? It should state != in my while. and of course that function should be a double... :(

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Okay, then... :)

Comment: So I changed it into: 

        double functie(double a,double b,double c,double d,double x){
            double y;
            y = (a*x*x*x + b*x*x + c*x + d);
            return y;
        }
        
       **identical**
    
        while(functie(a,b,c,d,max) != 0 ||functie(a,b,c,d,min) != 0 ){
                                   cout << "loop starts with: " << temp << endl;
    **identical**

and now it will find the root, but never get out of the loop...
Is there something that will stop the loop from the moment that it is close enough to the root?

Comment: For a half-interval search, `max` and `min` *do* have to change.

Comment: @user1009013 Try to inspect the values of `max`, `min` and `temp` _inside_ the loop.

Comment: I let it iterate with a for-loop(instead of the while-loop) for 100 times and that is enough. The pastie is at: http://pastebin.com/U6MXrvw6 (some things in dutch :p)

Answer (score 1):

Several comments on your program:

You should be returning double in your `functie` function:

```
double functie(double a,double b,double c,double d,double x){
    return  (a*x*x*x + b*x*x + c*x + d);
}
```

As FlopCoder noted this check is not correct:

```
while(functie(a,b,c,d,max) == 0 ||functie(a,b,c,d,min) == 0 )
```

You need to check that they are neither at root point, not that any of the two is at. However I will modify it a bit further because there is a small specific when comparing with doubles.

```
double epsilon = 1e-10;
while(fabs(functie(a,b,c,d,max)) > epsilon
        && fabs(functie(a,b,c,d,min)) > epsilon){
```

Note that I compare with one very small, still not zero constant. Doubles will never become equal to zero (I am getting the absolute value because we need to check whether we are sufficiently close to zero on either side.